# Why can't I send mail with correct informations?

Tags: php, forms, email, gmail

I am currently creating a site that includes a form, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/devis.css">
        <title>Devis Installation</title>
        <script>
            function validateEmail() {
                var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;

                if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
                    alert("Veuillez entrer une adresse e-mail valide.");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            // Empêche l'envoi du formulaire si l'adresse e-mail n'est pas valide
            document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (!validateEmail()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }})
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Installation - Demande de Devis</h2>
        <form action="php/process_form.php" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" value="Devis Installation">

            <label for="nom">Nom :</label>
            <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" required>

            <label for="prenom">Prénom :</label>
            <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" required>

            <label for="email">Adresse E-mail :</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

            <label for="adresse">Adresse :</label>
            <input type="text" id="adresse" name="adresse" required>

            <label for="telephone">Numéro de téléphone :</label>
            <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" required maxlength="10">

            <label for="codePostal">Code Postal :</label>
            <input type="text" id="codePostal" name="codePostal" required maxlength="5">

            <label for="ville">Ville :</label>
            <input type="text" id="ville" name="ville" required>

            <label for="description">Description du problème :</label>
            <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" required></textarea>

            <button type="submit">Envoyer la demande</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I send the message by e-mail, it says "From: groupentservices@gmail.com - To: groupentservices@gmail.com" The recipient's email is groupentservices@gmail.com but the sender's email must be the one retrieved from the form.

Here is the php code :

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(__DIR__ . '/..');
$dotenv->load();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $codePostal = $_POST['codePostal'];
    $ville = $_POST['ville'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // Configuration de PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $_ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'];
    $mail->Password = $_ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'];
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = 587;

    // Paramètres du message
    $mail->addAddress('groupentservices@gmail.com', 'GroupNtService');
    $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Demande de Devis - Installation';
    $mail->Body = "Nom : $nom<br>
                    Prénom : $prenom<br>
                    Adresse E-mail : $email<br>
                    Adresse : $adresse<br>
                    Numéro de téléphone : $telephone<br>
                    Code Postal : $codePostal<br>
                    Ville : $ville<br>
                    Description du problème : $description";

    // Envoi du message
    try {
        $mail->send();
        header("Location: /confirmation.html");
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Une erreur s'est produite : {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

The only thing I've found is to put:
`$mail->addReplyTo($email, $firstname . ' ' . $name);`
to get the sender's email.

Comment: Most email providers require the From address to be the authenticated user, or an email address on the domain. Gmail in particular is extremely strict about this.

Comment: Yes, but in the code : '$mail->addAddress('groupentservices@gmail.com', 'GroupNtService');' This is my email address and : '$mail->setFrom($email);' this is the sender's e-mail address

Comment: Right. Gmail in this case is rewriting the From address to be the authenticated user's address. Because email providers get really tetchy if you try to send from an address that isn't yours. Submitting a form doesn't mean consent to send an email as the submitter. If you want to be able to reply to the submitter, then use the ReplyTo address.

Comment: This is to prevent users from sending phishing email with spoofed From addresses.

Comment: Ok, so with Gmail I'm forced to use ReplyTo, there's no alternative.